# OpenBSD not accessible through SSH without GPU

Tags: ssh, x11, openbsd

I'm new to BSD and installed OpenBSD 6.3 to a test server for education purposes. It's going to be a dedicated firewall eventually.

During installation I used a graphics card to connect my monitor.
Now I would like to remove it to save space and power (it also builds up unnecessary heat). I'm only going to use it remotely for administration.
SSH works with gpu in place.
The problem is that it doesn't allow me to connect through SSH when I take out the GPU.

The server connects to network after boot.
I'm using standard generic kernel.

Should I try to disable X Windows?

I have a theory!

Maybe the boot process get stuck when trying to initialize the gpu? 
Network interfaces initialize before graphics right?
That explains why it’s listed on my network.

Is there a log I could look in to check what happens when I booted without the GPU?

Comment: You removed the GPU to save space? You don't need to remove the GPU to use the machine remotely. The machine should still boot. You could use `doas rcctl stop xenodm; doas rcctl disable xenodm` to turn off the graphical login (if you used `xenodm` before), but removing the GPU should not make the SSH daemon stop working...  Are you using the standard generic kernel?

Comment: Don't use OpenBSD then. Why do you need that specific OS, which is kind of notorious for issues working w/o a graphics card?

Comment: @ajeh The user _removed their graphics card_. You comment serves no purpose. If you are unable to help, then refrain from spreading rumours.

Comment: @Kusalananda There is always more than one way to skin a cat. And this is not a popularity contest. In layman terms, you do not own a monopoly for commenting on this resource. Live with that. The OP may be fighting an uphill battle that he has no chance of winning, if he is trying to make work something which does not, while something else (like Linux for instance) would work OOB without effort. I run Linux boxes where I can insert and remove graphics cards w/o any other actions required to SSH in. So it's for the OP to decide what they want, not for you.

Comment: @ajeh And I run a OpenBSD box with no GPU. So, there.  SSH is not reliant on GPU anywhere.

Comment: Were you able to connect to the machine before you removed the GPU?

Comment: Also, have you customized any firewall rules, and is the `sshd` daemon actually running?

Comment: Yes I successfully connected with SSH when the gpu was installed.

Comment: Given that OpenBSD's primary commercial role is in firewall type applications, the notion that it won't work without a GPU seems farfetched at best. Now, installing OpenBSD with a GPU then removing it obviously might lead to issues. I have sys admin friend whose primary OS of choice is OpenBSD, and none of his small servers or routers or firewall boxes have gpus, obviously. On such devices, you install using a serial cable, usb to serial usually, a specific configuration of cable, null modem, not the regular straight connector type.

Comment: It really shouldn't matter whether you have a GPU or not and if you remove it between boots. If you really won't be using X, you can just disable xenodm: `rcctl disable xenodm` and see if it boots. `sshd`is started before `xenodm`, so it should be running by then. Maybe the kernel is panicking for some reason. `/var/log/messages`and `/var/log/daemon` might have something interesting. Using a serial console (serial port + null modem cable) would be ideal to debug this and to manage the box in the future. (oh, and @ajeh: that is a lie, plain and simple, whether malicious or just ignorant)